# Custom URI parsing with android.net.Uri

Tags: android, uri

Let's say I have a custom URI format such as `aaa:<ID>` where ID is an integer.

I'd like to parse it in my android app with `android.net.Uri.parse(String)` method:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("aaa:12345");
```

As expected `aaa` can be accessed via `uri.getScheme()`.

But I can't find any way to access the `12345` part though I expected it to be returned by `uri.getPath()` or `uri.getAuthority()` (which both return `null`).

The URI seems compliant with [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) though, isn't it ?

Comment: `In the interest of performance, this class performs little to no validation. Behavior is undefined for invalid input. This class is very forgiving--in the face of invalid input, it will return garbage rather than throw an exception unless otherwise specified.` .... Use `java.net.URI` instead `android.net.Uri`...

Comment: Same result with `java.net.URI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `12345` part can be accessed by `uri.getSchemeSpecificPart()`